# XSLT 2.0 for loop one XML node which matches with data in other XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to loop through below XML B on Root node which matches with XML A with the XSLT pseudo code as given below. As i'm new to XSLT please help

XML A:

```
<P_OUT_PARTNUMBERS>
        <Row>
            <Column>53</Column>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Column>54</Column>
        </Row>
</P_OUT_PARTNUMBERS>
```

XML B:

```
<P_OUT_PARTNUMBERS>
        <Root>
            <Field>53</Field>
        </Root>
        <Root>
            <Field>30</Field>
        </Root>
</P_OUT_PARTNUMBERS>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$XMLB/Root">
    <xsl:variable name="Fieldvalue" select ="/Field"/>
    <xsl:if test="$XMLA/Row[Column = $Fieldvalue]/Column" >
          <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want something like below as i don't want to loose value of position() because of if condition. i.e. position() value should be 1,2,3,..etc with my logic i'm getting 1,3,6,8,..etc not continuos

Comment: It is not clear what the wanted result of `1,2,3` relates to if both samples have exactly two items (i.e. `Root` and `Row` elements) to compare. So perhaps explain in plain English which elements you want to select or how the input is supposed to be mapped to a sequence of integers like `1,2,3`. If your code gives `1,3,6,8` then please post minimal but complete working samples demonstrating that.

Comment: position() function within for-each loop must give 1,2,3.. i.e continuous numbers. Right now i have if condition within for-each loop because of which the position() value doesn't give continuous numbers

Comment: You are using the `<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>` inside of the `xsl:if`, if that is not what you want then move it outside. But I would suggest you stop thinking in terms of "loops" and rather try to explain which input nodes you want to select and how you want to map them to exactly which output sequence.

Comment: I want to output position() value. I want this position() to return 1,2,3,4...etc after if condition. what happens is if if condition satisfies then position() value increments which I don't want to happen

Comment: We miss the desired output corresponding to your input files. Please edit your question to add the missing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `position()` function doesn't do the job you expect or want it to do we will have a hard time to understand what you want to achieve if your explanation relies on asking `position()` something it doesn't do. What is the task in terms of input/output mapping?

If you want to process `P_OUT_PARTNUMBERS/Root[key('col', Field, $docA)]` then perhaps just do that with a key e.g. `<xsl:key name="col" match="P_OUT_PARTNUMBERS/Row" use="Column"/>`. In general moving conditions from nested `xsl:if`s to a simple predicate might be more along the lines of having a continuous sequence.